# How to implement echo server with boost::spawn?

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine, spawn, asio

I would like to convert [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) asynchronous echo server to the same server, but using boost :: spawn.

I've tried this, but I'm facing various problems:

1. it is not possible to pass a non-static function to spawn. I want to pass a function, and not write a lambda every time (as is done in the example echo server with boost :: spawn on the boost site)
2. even if I wrap the function call in a lambda, then I don't quite understand how I can hang my custom callback? how can I call another function in boost :: spawn in this callback (for example, I would like to call do_read from do_read again)?

Could someone use an example from the link to show how such a mechanism is correctly implemented?

My code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using executor_type = boost::asio::any_io_executor;

class session
        : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
    session(tcp::socket socket)
            : socket_(std::move(socket))
    {
    }

    void start()
    {
        boost::asio::spawn(socket_.get_executor(), [this]        (boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
            do_read_init(yield);
        });
    }

private:
    void do_read_init(boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
        do_read(yield);
        do_read_init(yield);
    }
    void do_read(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_,     max_length), yield);
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};

class server: public std::enable_shared_from_this<server> {
public:
    server(
            executor_type exe, short port)
            : acceptor_(exe, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
    }

    void start() { do_accept(); }
    void stop() { acceptor_.close(); }

private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
                [this, self = shared_from_this()] //
                        (boost::system::error_code ec,     tcp::socket socket) {
                    if (!ec) {
                        std::make_shared<session>    (std::move(socket))->start();
                        do_accept();
                    }
                });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        {

            auto s = std::make_shared<server>    (io_context.get_executor(), 21);
            s->start();
        }

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I try to start reading data using spawn, and then go to read again, but the first attempt succeeds, and the second one fails.
Also, I do not understand how to hang up a callback on the reader, where I can get both the error code and write further logic.

Comment: I think you need to show at least the code that is not working, so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could try it with boost::bind. "https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_functions_and_fu". If you are fine with coroutine-ts you can look at this example client using co_spawn and bind. "https://github.com/werto87/client_template"

Comment: i add code example

Comment: Is there a reason why you use boost coroutine and not boost::coroutine-ts? If coroutine-ts is okay for you I can give you an example.

Comment: Sorry, but i need only boost coroutine :(